# For $x>0$, $x + \frac1x \ge 2$ and equality holds if and only if $x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that for $x>0$, $x + \frac1x \ge 2$ and equality holds if and only if $x=1$.

I have proven that $x+ \frac1x \ge 2$ by re-writing it as $x^2 -2x +1 \ge0$ and factoring to $(x-1)^2\ge0$ which is true because you cannot square something and it be negative.

Now I am stuck on the part where I have to prove equality to hold if and only if $x=1$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with "ordered fields" but with calculus and/or algebra...and I think you're suppsoed to prove it is **an equality** iff $\;x=1\;$ , *not* that "it is true"

Comment: Inspired by one of [lab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee)'s answers sometime ago:

apply [A.M.-G.M.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) to $\left(x,\dfrac 1x\right)$ to solve the problem at once.

Comment: We have not gotten into Calculus in my proofs class yet and this is in the "ordered fields" section of the text so I assumed it was an ordered fields question. Yes I meant I have to prove equality holds if and only if x=1.

Comment: What is the only value of $x$ satisfying $(x - 1)^2 = 0$? It's the *repeated root* of the quadratic: $x = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that $x+\frac{1}{x}=2$ if and only if $x=1$.

Continuing what you did, we have $(x-1)^2=0$ if and only if $x-1=0$ if and only if $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more elegant one:

$$\left(\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) ^ 2 \ge 0$$
$$x - 2 + \frac{1}{x} \ge 0$$
$$x + \frac{1}{x} \ge 2$$