# Show that if x>0, x+1/x >= 2.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How am I to prove this inequality without use of calculus: for any real x>0, x+1/x >= 2 ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove this inequality $ x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2 $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705064/how-to-prove-this-inequality-x-frac1x-geq-2)

Answer (score 4):

$$x+\frac{1}{x}-2=\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x}=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}\ge 0$$

Comment: Or $\ x+\frac{1}{x}-2=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}})^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean inequality.

$$\frac {x + y} 2 \ge \sqrt {xy}$$

for $x, y \ge 0$

Comment: AM-GM is $\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k}{k}\ge \sqrt[k]{a_1a_2\cdots a_k}$, which is not so simple to prove and overkill here where we can simply complete the square, as shown in Alexey's answer.

Comment: The simple case of $\frac {x + y} 2 \ge \sqrt{xy}$ can be granted as given. I find this simpler. "Easier" is subjective.

Comment: And this way is easy to generalise to $n$ positive numbers and their inverses.