# Find the max or min value of the function $y = x + \frac{16}{x+3}$ where $x > 0$, without using differentiation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Question:**

> Find the max or min value of the function
>
> $$y = x + \frac{16}{x+3}$$
>
> where $x > 0$, without using differentiation.

I don't know how to solve this. How do I determine if it is a minimum or maximum?

Comment: You can have a look at [How to prove this inequality $ x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2 $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705064/how-to-prove-this-inequality-x-frac1x-geq-2) and other related questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Martin. I can understand how to prove x+1/x >= 2 now

Comment: The body of your Question should contain a full statement of the problem, not relying wholly on the title to pose it.  See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is no max value for $f(x)$, but a min value does exist. Observe that for $x > 0$,
$$
f(x) = x + \frac{16}{x+3} = \color{red}{x + 3 + \frac{16}{x+3}} - 3 \geq \color{red}{8} - 3 = 5
$$
When $x+3 = 4$, the equality holds, thus the min value is $5$.

---

Here, the fact $a + b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}, a, b > 0$ is used.

Comment: -filler- nice work.

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is non-negative for $x>0.$

First write the function as
$$y=\frac{x^2+3x+16}{x+3},$$
and keep subtracting and adding $x+3$ from the numerator until it is factorable.   This gives 
$$y=\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x+3}+5.$$
The zero of the fraction is $x=1,$ giving minimum value $y=5.$

Comment: Nice +1. You may want to write that as $\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{x+3}+5$, so it self-certifies the minimum for $\mathbb R^+$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
x &> 0 \\
x + 3 &> 3 \\
y &= x + \frac{16}{x + 3}
\end{align}

$$ \text{A little trick:} $$

$$ y + 3 = x + 3 + \frac{16}{x + 3} $$

$$ \text{It is easy to prove that } $$

\begin{align}
a, b &> 0 \\
a + b &\geq 2\sqrt{ab}
\end{align}

$$ \text {so now:} $$

\begin{align}
a + b &\geq 2\sqrt{ab} \\
(x + 3) + \frac{16}{x + 3} &\geq 2\sqrt{(x + 3) \times \frac{16}{x + 3}} = 2 \times 4 = 8 \\
y + 3 = (x + 3) + \frac{16}{x + 3} &\geq 8 \\
y + 3 &\geq 8 \\
y &\geq 5
\end{align}

Comment: Maybe it is important to add that $y=5$ is indeed attained (for $x+3=4$, i.e., for $x=1$; this fulfills the requirement $x>0$.)

Comment: Thanks once again. It is quite difficult.

Comment: do you want to solve it with $\Delta$ in quadratic equation  ?

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x+\frac{16}{x+3}\\(x+3)y=x(x+3)+16\\x^2+3x+16-xy-3y=0\\x^2+x(3-y)+(16-3y)=0\\ \Delta \geq0\\(3-y)^2-4(1)(16-3y) \geq 0\\y^2+9-6y-64+12y \geq0\\(y-5)(y+11) \geq 0\\y \leq-11 \space\space or \space \space y\geq 5\\ $$ as we know about $x> 0 \rightarrow y >0$ so  $$ y\geq 5 $$

Comment: This answer is more easy to understand. Thanks again