# How to prove $\frac xy + \frac yx \ge 2$

Tags: inequality, integers, parity

I am practicing some homework and I'm stumped.

The question asks you to prove that

$x \in Z^+, y \in Z^+$

$\frac xy + \frac yx \ge 2$

So I started by proving that this is true when x and y have the same parity, but I'm not sure how to proceed when x and y have opposite partiy

This is my proof so far for opposite parity

$x,y \in Z^+ $ $|$ $x \gt 0,$ $y \gt 0$. Let x be even $(x=2a, $ $ a \in Z^+)$ and y be odd $(y=2b+1, $ $b \in Z^+)$. Then,

$\frac xy + \frac yx \ge 2$

$\frac {2a}{2b+1} + \frac {2b+1}{2a} \ge 2$

$\frac {2b^2 + 4a^2 + 4a + 1}{2b(2a+1)} \ge 2$

$4b^2 + 4a^2 +4a + 1 \ge 4b(2a+1)$

$4b^2 + 4a^2 + 4a +1 \ge 8ab + 4b$

$4b^2 - 4b + (2a + 1)^2 \ge 8ab$

$(2b-1)^2 + 1 + (2a+1)^2 \ge 8ab$

I feel like this is the not the correct way to go about proving it, but I can't think of a better way to do it. Does anyone have any suggestions? Just hints please, not a solution.

Comment: Hint:
Since you know that x and y are positive. you can multiply the inequality by xy.

Comment: @Sorfosh This helps give intuition as to why it is true, however in any correctly worded proof the desired inequality is the *last* line, not the first.

Comment: How do you prove the above inequality is true when x and y have same parity?

Comment: We know that $a+\frac1a\ge2$ for any $a>0$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705064/how-to-prove-this-inequality-x-frac1x-geq-2) (and maybe other posts [linked to that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/705064) might be of interest, too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider multiplying both sides of the inequality by $xy$, which is **positive**. Then, we have:
$$\frac xy + \frac yx \ge 2\\
x^2+y^2\ge 2xy
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: I will point out as I did in the comments on the original post, that proving that if we assume the desired inequality is true leads to a tautology, this is not the same as proving that the desired inequality is actually true.  For trivial counterexample, $5\leq 3 \Rightarrow 5\cdot 0 \leq 3\cdot 0\Rightarrow 0\leq 0$ and we know that $0\leq 0$ is true, however this doesn't imply that $5\leq 3$.  A correctly worded proof will have the desired inequality at the *end*, not at the beginning of the proof.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree in a sense with you, but in that specific case we move through "$\iff$" and not just implications.

Answer (score 8):

Clearly $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$

So $x^2-2xy+y^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy $

Since $x $ and $y$ are positive integers , $x \neq 0 $ and $y \neq 0$.

Thus we can divide by $xy$.

So we have $\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy} \geq \frac {2xy}{xy} \Rightarrow \frac {x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \geq 2$.

Comment: Clear, concise +1

Comment: As the OP stated "*Just hints please, not a solution.*", I recommend putting at least half of this in spoiler by using `>!`

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree on that matter, but everybody seems to be already giving full solutions anyway.

Answer (score 4):

$$(x-y)^2\geq0$$

> $$\begin{array}{l}x^2-2xy+y^2\geq0\\x^2+y^2\geq2xy\\\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}\geq2\\\frac{x^2}{xy}+\frac{y^2}{xy}\geq2\\\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geq2\\QED\end{array}$$

This will work for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$

Comment: As the OP stated "*Just hints please, not a solution.*", I recommend putting at least half of this in spoiler by using `>!`

Comment: Hmm >! didn't work right. Let me try again.

Comment: I recommend `>!$\begin{array}{l} x^2-2xy+y^2\geq 0\\ ... QED\end{array}$`

Comment: That didn't make the spoiler tag work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still learning a lot of SE syntax.

Comment: Doesn't work for $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, only works when $x$ and $y$ are nonzero and have the same sign.

Answer (score 3):

For every $a$ you have $(a-1)^2\geq 0$, so $a^2+1\geq 2a$.

If $a>0$ you have $a+\frac 1a\geq 2.$ Take $a=\frac xy$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y,$ then it is true.

Suppose $x>y$ then there is exists positive integer $n$ such that $x=y+n.$

This implies $\frac{x}{y}=1+\frac{n}{y}$ and $\frac{y}{x}=1-\frac{n}{x}$.
Adding these equations, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{y}+ \frac{y}{x}=2+n\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=2+n\frac{x-y}{xy}> 2\quad as\quad x>y.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(t) = t+{1 \over t}$ on $t >0$. $f$ is convex and $f'(1) = 0$, hence $1$ is a global maximiser. Hence $f(t) \ge f(1) = 2$ for all $t > 0$.

Hence ${x \over y} + { y \over x} = f({x \over y}) \ge 2$ for all $x,y>0$.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is the only downvote in this whole page. Please explain what differentiates this answer in a bad way?

Answer (score 1):

You answer is correct but you went the wrong way near the end. (Plus you have  minor error in it (you swapped a and b somewhere which doesn't really change the problem).

You had: 
$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geq2$

$\frac{2a}{2b+1}+\frac{2b+1}{2a}\geq2$

$\frac{4a^2+4b^2+4\color{red}b+1}{2\color{red}a(2\color{red}b+1)}$

$4a^2+4b^2+4b+1\geq4a(2b+1)$

$4a^2+4b^2+-8ab-4a+4b+1\geq0$

$(2a+2b-1)^2\geq0$

Answer (score 0):

Here is "another" simple method(this is essentially same as completing the square.) of proving $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geq 2$ by the help of [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) :

Consider the set $\{\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{x}\}.$

Applying AM-GM Inequality on these two values , we have :

$$\frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}}{2} \geq \sqrt {\frac {x}{y} \times \frac{y}{x}}$$

$$\implies \frac{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}}{2} \geq \sqrt {1}$$

$$\implies \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \geq 1 \times 2$$

$$\implies \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \geq 2$$

Hople this helps. :)

Comment: Why a set is needed to apply AM-GM ?

Comment: Also other answers include AM-GM inequality but for a special case.

Comment: @A---B No need of any set .... It is just to "collect" all the elements on which the AM-Gm has to applied. Sometimes people get confused on which values AM-GM has been applied. To avoid that confusion, I have explicitly mentioned the elements on which AM-GM has been applied....

Comment: @A---B I have already mentioned that AM-GM for 2 values is essentially same as completing the square....

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we assume $t:=\frac{x}{y}\geq 1,$ we see that the $t+\frac{1}{t}$ has its derivative non-negative, so $t+\frac{1}{t}\geq 2.$

Answer (score 0):

By [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

$$\frac xy + \frac yx = x\cdot \frac 1 y + y \cdot \frac 1x\ge x\cdot \frac 1 x + y \cdot \frac 1y=1+1=2$$