# How to find the sup, inf, max and min for the set $H=\{ x \in \Bbb R : x+\frac3x-1 \le 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $H=\{ x \in \Bbb R : x+\frac3x-1 \le 0\}$.  Find $\sup(H)$, $\max(H)$, $\inf(H)$, and $\min(H)$. I understand the terminology but I am new to this please just offer any first steps or any help on how to get started.

Comment: oh wow sorry I do not know how format my question

Comment: You may want to see the [formatting guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189).

Comment: I think that this title is not good for a question if you intend that others will enjoy the future answers that you'll get here.

Comment: If a min exists, it is also the inf.  If a max exists, it is also the sup.

Comment: oh yeah sorry about that, @RafaelWagner

Comment: Could I find the min/max by taking the limit of the function? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Try to [draw a graph of $x + \frac3x -1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B3%2Fx-1).

Comment: I found the max to be (-\sqrt{3}, -2\sqrt{3}-1) and the min to just be the positive version of the max, is that correct? If so then have I found the Sup and Inf?

Comment: We don't want the $\max$ etc. of the values of $x+\frac 3x-1$, we just want to find the whole range of $x$ where it is less than zero.  Then we find the $\sup$ etc. of that set.

Answer (score 1):

As the expression on the left is continuous, the values of $x$ for which it is true will form one or more intervals.  The transitions will either be where $x+\frac 3x-1=0$ or where it is undefined, so solve the equation, add $0$ to the set of roots because the expression is undefined there, and assess the truth of the inequality on each resulting interval.  Can you then find the $\inf, \sup, \max, \min$ once you have the interval(s)?

Comment: I found the max to be (-\sqrt{3}, -2\sqrt{3}-1) and the min to just be the positive version of the max, is that correct? If so then have I found the Sup and Inf? @RossMillikan

Comment: No, I don't find any real roots of the quadratic.

Comment: i''m sorry then I cannot understand what I need to do

Comment: Once you know that there are no real roots of the quadratic, the only place the sign can change is $0$.  If you evaluate the expression at $x=1$ you find $x+\frac 3x-1 \gt 0$ so the positive numbers are not in $H$.  Now evaluate the expression at some convenient negative number, like $x=-1$.  If it is greater than zero, then $H$ is empty.  If it is less than zero, $H=(-\infty,0)$.  Then you need to find the $\inf, \sup, \max, \min$ of $H$

Comment: That was extremely helpful you are a saint thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

Notice that we have 
$$x+\frac3x \ge 2\sqrt3$$
for $x>0$. There are various ways to show this, you can have a look at several posts with proofs of 
[similar inequality $x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705064).

Let us denote $f(x)=x+\frac3x-1$. For $x>0$ you have
$$f(x) = x+\frac3x-1 \ge 2\sqrt3-1 >0.$$
And for $x<0$ you have
$$f(x) = -\left(|x|+\frac3{|x|}\right) -1 \le -2\sqrt3 - 1 <0.$$

So you can see that $f(x)>0$ for positive values and $f(x)<0$ for negative values. (You can also try to [sketch the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B3%2Fx-1) to see this.)

Which basically means that
$$H=\{x\in\mathbb R; f(x)\le 0 \} = \{x\in\mathbb R; x<0\}.$$
Now that you have much simpler description of $H$, it should be easier to find supermum, infimum, maximum, minimum of $H$ (if they exist).