# Quadratic equation and inequality of solution

Tags: inequality, quadratics

I have a quadratic equation, $bx^2 + 2ax + b =0$, with, $a>b>0$.
I can solve this as followings,
$x_{+} = \frac{- a +\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b},x_{-} = \frac{- a -\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b},$

In my text book, an inequality equation, $x_{+}^{2} < 1 < x_{-}^2$, is written with the solution, but I cannot derive the equation. If you can, please teach me the derivation.
Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

Given $x_{+} = \frac{- a +\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b},x_{-} = \frac{- a -\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b}$,  the following is true with a>b>0 :

|$x_{-}| = |\frac{ a +\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b}| >|\frac{ a +\sqrt{b^2 - b^2}}{a}=1$
, |$x_{+}| = |\frac{- a +\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b}|<|\frac{- b +\sqrt{a^2 - a^2}}{b}|=1$,

$\to$|$x_{+}|^{2} < 1 < |x_{-}|^2$,   $x_{+}^{2} < 1 < x_{-}^2$

Comment: Thanks, Bright Star. My mind is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

From $bx^2+2ax+b=0$, we can compute the discriminant, of which $4(a^2-b^2)>0$, and we conclude that there are two distinct roots. Furthermore since $a>0$, $b>0$, the roots must be negative.

Hence $x_- < x_+<0$

Also,

$$x^2+\frac{2a}{b}+1=0$$

From the constant term,we can conclude that $x_+x_-=1$,  hence $x_- < -1 < x_+<0$.

Hence, we must have $x_+^2 <1 < x_-^2$.

Comment: Thanks, Siong. I caught up your calculation. This make me clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have expressions for the zeroes $ \ x_{+} \ = \ \frac{- a +\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b} \ , \ x_{-} = \frac{- a -\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{b} \ \ , $ with  $ \ a \ > \ b \ > \ 0 \ \ . $  So we can first determine that
$$ \frac{   \sqrt{a^2  \ - \  b^2}}{b} \ \ = \ \ \frac{  a· \sqrt{1  \ - \  \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^2}}{b} \ \ < \ \ \frac{a}{b} \ \ , $$
and thus,
$$ - \ \frac{  a· \sqrt{1  \ - \  \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^2}}{b} \ \ < \ \ 0 \ \ < \ \  \frac{  a· \sqrt{1  \ - \  \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^2}}{b} \ \ < \ \ \frac{a}{b} $$ $$\Rightarrow \ \ x_{-} \ = \ -\frac{a}{b} \ - \ \frac{  a· \sqrt{1  \ - \  \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^2}}{b} \ \ < \ \ -\frac{a}{b} \ \ < \ \  x_{+} \ = \ -\frac{a}{b} \ - \ \frac{  a· \sqrt{1  \ - \  \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^2}}{b} \ \ < \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

A quadratic polynomial of the form $ \ A·x^2 + B·x + A \ $ is called palindromic, a characteristic of which is that if $ \ r \ $ is a zero, then $ \ \frac{1}{r} \ $ is also.  (A proof of this is suggested by the second paragraph of **Siong Thye Goh**'s answer.)  So $ \ x_{-} \ = \ \frac{1}{x_{+}} \ \ . $  We can also demonstrate this by direct calculation:
$$ \frac{1}{x_{+}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{b}{- a \ + \ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{b · ( \ - a \ - \ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} \ )}{( \ - a \ + \ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\ ) \ · \ ( \ - a \ - \ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} \ )} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{b · ( \ - a \ - \ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} \ )}{ a^2 \ - \ (a^2 - b^2  )} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ - a \ - \ \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}  }{ b} \ \ = \ \ x_{-} \ \ . $$
We find (from Viete, for instance) that the sum of the roots is $ \ x_{+} + x_{-} \ = \ -\frac{2a}{b} \ < \ -2 \ \ . $  It follows that
$$ \left( x_{+} \ + \ \frac{1}{x_{+}} \right)^2 \ \ = \ \ x^2_{+} \ + \ 2 \ + \ \frac{1}{x^2_{+}} \ \ > \ \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2_{+} \ + \  \frac{1}{x^2_{+}} \ \ > \ \ 2 \ \ . $$
From the AM-GM inequality [and many other starting points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705064/how-to-prove-this-inequality-x-frac1x-geq-2), we can show that $ \  a \ + \ \frac{1}{a} \ \ge \ 2 \ \ $ for $ \ a > 0 \ \ , $ with equality holding for $ \ a = 1 \ \ . $  Our result indicates then that the larger of $ \ x^2_{+} \ $ or $ \ \frac{1}{x^2_{+}} \ $ must be greater than $ \ 1 \ \ . $  Since we have $ \ x_{-} \ < \ x_{+} \ < \ 0 \ \ , $ we conclude that $ \ x^2_{-} \ $ is the larger of the two and hence $ \ x^2_{+} \ < \ 1 \  < \ x^2_{-} \ \ . $